# Controller not receiving Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I can get this to work. I have am sending Json from a JS File to a controller but the controller receive a null object.

This is my JS:

```
 var MyJson2 = JSON.stringify(resultItems);
             console.log(MyJson2);
             $.ajax({

                 url: "/mainMap/receiveGeoID",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: MyJson2,
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 error: function (response) {
                     alert("error");
                 },
                 success: function (response) {
                     alert("success");
                 }

             });
```

And this is the Json when I debug the program:

[image]

My model looks like this:

```
  public class CensusModelList
{
    public List<CensusReceive> CensusList { get; set; }

}

public class CensusReceive
{
    string GEOID { get; set; }

}
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult receiveGeoID(CensusModelList CensusData)
    {
        var test = CensusData;
        return View();

    }
```

Is seem that cannot get the Json:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is wrong, if you look at your Json you're receiving an array of items, but your model expects a single object which contains a property named CensusList which is an array of CensusReceived, thus the deserialization results in a null object because it does not match.

The easiest way to fix it is to change your function as this:

```
public ActionResult receiveGeoID(CensusReceive[] CensusData)
```

In that case the model will match your received data.

Also, the GEOID property must be public or the deserializer will not find it and will be null.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that is receiving objects now however the objects are empty.

Comment: Add the definition of CensusReceive class, there should be an error on it.

Comment: Very strange, it looks ok to me, can you retry again and verify the sent data is correct?

Comment: It gives me 147 objects however in every object in the debugging process it says GEOID | null

Comment: :D I see what's wrong now XD, make GEOID public, if it's not public the serializer cannot acces the property.